# How to draw multi color on muliple waypoints on google map in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hi i'm creating path with multiple way-points on google map. i want to add different color for each way-points. i tried with poly-lines but didn't work. it's showing only one color.

Please find code below:

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points;
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                    points = new ArrayList<>();
                    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions  = new PolylineOptions();
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                        try {
                            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                            points.add(position);
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                    polyLineOptions.width(4);
                    int color = getRandomColor();
                    polyLineOptions.color(color);
                    if (polyline != null) {
                        polyline.remove();
                    }
                    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public int getRandomColor() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at my project here: https://github.com/antoniocarlon/richmaps

Comment: thank you... let me try @antonio